# Meteor build locally or on aws host

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, docker

A Meteor app is running on the local machine. Then it gets built `appDir$ Meteor build .` and the resultant myApp.tar.gz gets copied to the AWS cloud. Then a script runs on the cloud to put the app into a docker container following some Dockerfile commands.

Every time a change needs to be done, a repeat of the above follows, any better way to reduce the effort of re- building/copying/dockerizing?

Is it possible by using volume and docker-compose and just sync the changes from the local development machine to the aws EC2 volume directory? How?

```
//Dockerfile on AWS EC2
FROM lambdalinux/baseimage-amzn:2016.09-000

RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y tar nodejs

ADD ./myApp.tar.gz /opt/
EXPOSE 80

ENV ROOT_URL http://example.com
ENV MONGO_URL "mongodb://username:pass..."
ENV PORT 80

# Install nodejs modules
WORKDIR /opt/bundle/
RUN npm install fibers 
RUN npm install underscore 
RUN npm install source-map-support 
RUN npm install semver

# Start the app
CMD node ./main.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command called rsync that will do a smart sync of a whole directory structure - if you unpacked the build locally you could then rsync it up to the server.

It can use either file dates or checksums to work out what has changed, and will make the process quicker. Minified files will probably change every time, but certainly many assets won't change every time.

I would set it up with a mirror of your production directory, sync the files into there, do some (automated) sanity checks first, and then switch the new version into place. If it doesn't work you can switch the old version back. There is a little work required to get this set up, but it will make deployment faster/easier